# Stub require in node js

Tags: node.js, require, sinon

Is it any way to stub `require` in `node js` using `sinon.js`?

For example, i have some file:

```
const myModule = require('awesomeModule');
```

And I want to have such stub in my tests:

```
myRequireStub.withArgs('awesomModule').throws(new Error('some error'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');

let myRequireStub = sinon.stub(module, 'require');

myRequireStub.withArgs('awesomeModule').throws(new Error('some error'));

const myModule = require('awesomeModule');
// Error: some error
```

However, by stubbing `require` you'll pretty much break the ability to load modules, so I'm not sure how useful this is.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usage, it's probably best to use a library such as [mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery) or [mock-require](https://github.com/boblauer/mock-require). But I needed a way to stub *all* calls to require, so this is what I came up with:

```
const _module = require('module');

let require = sinon.stub(_module, '_load');

//return a function that returns a function
require.returns(() => { return () => {}; });

//run code that calls require

require.restore();

assert(require.calledWith('module-name'));
```